# How to consume url parameters in Django views

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Getting an error always

```
The current path, <code>api/det/1</code>, didn’t match any of these.
```

My urls.py

```
 url(r'^api/det/<int:id>',views.DetailsAPI.as_view(),name='DetailsAPI')
```

My views.py

```
class DetailsAPI(APIView):
    def get(self,id): 
        filter_list=Details.objects.all()
        #filter_list = Details.objects.get(id=id)
        envid = self.kwargs['id']
        df = read_frame(filter_list)
        df_det = df.loc[df['Id'] == int(id)]
        df_final=df_det.to_json(orient='records')
        return HttpResponse(df_final, content_type = 'application/json')
```

I'm sure there is some simple stuff that i'm missing and i can't get it to work with whatever syntax i try.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? You use `url()` in your urls.py but use the new syntax for `path`

Comment: put debug mode on and check the url patterns available

Comment: @lain Shelvington yes, i think i messed up with the version.. changing the url to url(r'^api/det/(?P<id>\d+)',views.DetailsAPI.as_view(),name='DetailsAPI') worked out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the url to the below one worked.

```
url(r'^api/det/(?P<id>\d+)',views.DetailsAPI.as_view(),name='DetailsAPI')
```